# How to change efficiently Colormap of big .fig files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, colormap, acoustics

I have some 2 GB .fig files where I would like to change colormaps smartly. 
The initial colormap is `colormap(1-gray(1024));` made initially for computers. 
I would like to change smoothly to Parula etc for visualization purposes. 
There is a need for changing to many different colormaps efficiently. 
It may be the case that the original `gray` is not the optimum for the starting point.

My main interest is the time-series analysis with Mathematica where I need to find some colormap which I can use with meshgrid data structure. 
There are some colormaps presented in the book *[Passive Acoustic Monitoring of Cetaceans](http://www.wmxz.eu/)* by Walter M.X. Zimmer which seem to be relevant here. Some alternatives to be considered

1. `colormap(1-gray(1024))`
2. `colormap(1-gray(12))`
3. `colormap(1-gray)`
4. `colormap(cmap)`
5. `colormap(1-gray(7*2))`
6. `colormap(1-gray(8*2))`

The situation is that changing from one colormap to another is too slow with big .fig files. Little (or no?) history is taken into account when changing the colormap, I think. The previous change of a colormap does not decrease the execution time of the next colormap; although you would change subsequently back to the initial colormap. The biggest problem is with colormaps that are not injective with each other. 
Questions

- Why do they take *everything except* clauses (`1-gray`)?
- How can you change smoothly colormap of big .fig files in Matlab? There are similarities between some colormaps. Sometimes, the default way etc `colormap(parula(200))` is too slow. I would like to speed up things if similarities between colormaps could be used; by configuring the initial colormap suitable for some changes of colormaps.
- How can you decide a colormap such that it is usable for the time-series analysis in Mathematica? Just an example, please.

Comment: Your questions seem somewhat off-topic. The 1st one I find _difficult_ to reproduce, the 3rd one is not well-defined (what is considered "usable"?). As for the 2nd question, please explain what is wrong with the standard MATLAB way of changing colormaps using `colormap(parula(200))` etc. Did you benchmark this? Why do you think that a better solution exists?

Comment: @Dev-iL I provided answers to your questions. The situation is that changing from one colormap to another is too slow with big .fig files. Little (or no?) history is taken into account when changing the colormap, I think. The previous change of a colormap does not decrease the execution time of the next colormap; although you would change subsequently back to the initial colormap. The biggest problem is with colormaps that are not injective with each other.

Comment: The colormaps don't **need** to be injective because they are only a way to _display_ underlying data. If you have the figure file, you should be able to extract the data out of the figure (`CData`, `ZData` etc.) and replot it as you wish. That is, unless you are saving the figure as an image and trying to infer the value of the data based on the colormap in some other software (is this why you mentioned Mathematica?)... In that case I would suggest exporting the data from MATLAB in some format that doesn't require you to do image processing (`csv`?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use Mathematica 11 instead, since its default colormap has much better contrast and its viewer fits much better for your dynamic target.